# Bluetooth connection lost issue

Tags: android, bluetooth

This is not really something I'm developing, more like something I'm trying to debug. For some reason my HTC Desire HD keeps disconnecting from my car's bluetooth. It worked fine on phone's  original rom, then I upgraded to Gingerbread (HTC rom) and it started to disconnect. I'm not sure what happened next (possibly I've installed something? mb the car's computer was reset as I had a service?) but it actually started to work after a few months and all was good until I upgraded again to 2.3.5 (HTC official upgrade). The phone connects to my car without any issues, then looses the connection within a minute and will not reconnect until the phone or the car's restarted. Here's some log data that I was able to collect in case someone might be familiar with how the bluetooth works on android:

```
I//system/bin/btld(23506): ##### USERIAL_Ioctl: BT_Sleep, USERIAL_IO_BT_WAKE_DEASSERT ####
W/        (23507): bta_dm_pm_timer_cback 0x255fa4
W/        (23507): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/        (23507): proc dm_pm_timer expires
I//system/bin/btld(23506): ##### USERIAL_Ioctl: BT_Wake, USERIAL_IO_BT_WAKE_ASSERT ####
I/PTIM    (23507): Call GKI_add_to_timer_list in ptim_start_timer
W/        (23507): start dm_pm_timer:0, 5000
D/dalvikvm(23586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 381K, 48% free 3295K/6279K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+3ms
I/keystore( 1264): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
I/BtAtPhonebook( 1631): Refreshed phonebook ME with 255 results
I/keystore( 1264): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
I/BtAtPhonebook( 1631): Refreshed phonebook ME with 255 results
D/dalvikvm(15887): GC_EXPLICIT freed 124K, 44% free 4129K/7303K, external 0K/512K, paused 79ms
I//system/bin/btld(23506): ##### USERIAL_Ioctl: BT_Sleep, USERIAL_IO_BT_WAKE_DEASSERT ####
W/        (23507): stop dm_pm_timer:0
W/HeadsetBase.cpp( 1631): RFCOMM poll() returned  success (1), but with an unexpected revents bitmask: 0x11
I/HeadsetBase( 1631): headset read error 5
I//system/bin/btld(23506): send_ctrl_msg: [BTL_IFS CTRL] send BTLIF_DISCONNECT_IND (AG) 8 pbytes (hdl 18)
I//system/bin/btld(23506): BTL_IF_DisconnectDatapath: Disconnect datapath on handle 21
I//system/bin/btld(23506): wrp_setup_rxflow: wrp_setup_rxflow : 0 (fd 21)
I//system/bin/btld(23506): wsactive_del: delete wsock 21 from active list [212ef8]
I//system/bin/btld(23506): wrp_close_data: wrp_close 21 [brcm.bt.btlif]
I//system/bin/btld(23506): wsactive_del: delete wsock 21 from active list [212ef8]
I/BTL_IFC ( 1631): btl_ifc_ctrl_rx: [BTL_IFC CTRL] recv BTLIF_DISCONNECT_IND (AG) 10 pbytes (hdl 92)
D/BLZ_WRAPPER( 1631): blz_ctrl_msg: [blz ctrl] received message [BTLIF_DISCONNECT_IND]
D/BLZ_WRAPPER( 1631): blz_ctrl_msg: Channel disconnected remotely, rf_ch 65535
I/BTL_IFC_WRP( 1631): wrp_find_wsock_by_rfhdl: wrp_find_wsock_by_rfhdl : no entry found, lst 0, rfchan 65535
I/BLZ_WRAPPER( 1631): btl_if_close: btl_if_close (105)
D/BLZ_WRAPPER( 1631): btl_if_close: [btl_if_close] : (105:100), disc_pending 0, asnc 0, selct 0, flags 2
I/BTL_IFC ( 1631): send_ctrl_msg: [BTL_IFC CTRL] send BTLIF_DISCONNECT_REQ (AG) 8 pbytes (hdl 92)
W/        (23507):  Could not find conn_info for chdl=0x3
D/BluetoothHeadsetService( 1631): Device: 00:13:A9:A1:19:1E Headset state 2 -> 0, result = 0
W/        (23507): BTA_DM_LINK_DOWN_EVT::bdaddr 00:13:a9:a1:19:1e reason x15
D/DTUN_HCID4(23540): dtun_dm_sig_link_down()
I/DTUN_HCID4(23540): dtun_dm_sig_link_down device = 0xf750 handle = 256 reason = 0x15
I//system/bin/btld(23506): send_ctrl_msg: [BTL_IFS CTRL] send BTLIF_DTUN_SIGNAL_EVT (CTRL) 11 pbytes (hdl 17)
D/BTL_IFC_WRP( 1631): wrp_close_s_only: wrp_close_s_only [105] (105:100) [brcm.bt.btlif]
D/BTL_IFC_WRP( 1631): wrp_close_s_only: data socket closed
D/BTL_IFC_WRP( 1631): wsactive_del: delete wsock 105 from active list [ad3ca3c0]
I/DTUN_HCID4(23540): [embedded]LINK_DOWN name = UHP, address = 00:13:A9:A1:19:1E, reason = 0x15
D/BluetoothService( 1379): Device property changed:00:13:A9:A1:19:1E property:Connected
I/BluetoothHeadsetService( 1631): [embedded] HSP/HFP state : address: 00:13:A9:A1:19:1E name: UHP State:2->0
I/BTL_IFC ( 1631): send_ctrl_msg: [BTL_IFC CTRL] send BTLIF_DISCONNECT_REQ (SCO) 0 pbytes (hdl 102)
W/        (23507):  Could not find conn_info with active SCO
I/BluetoothA2dpService( 1379): BluetoothHeadset disconnected, remove AV CONNECT_TO msg
I/StatusBarPolicy( 1577): updateBluetooth bt icon:true,HS:0,A2DP:false
D/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1260): setDeviceConnectionState() device: 40, state 0, address 00:13:A9:A1:19:1E
I/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1260): setOutputDevice() output 4 device 0 delayMs 0
I/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1260): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 4
I/BluetoothDeviceProfileState( 1379): Entering IncomingHandsfree state with: 6
I/BluetoothDeviceProfileState( 1379): Processing command:6
I/BluetoothDeviceProfileState( 1379): Entering ACL Connected state with: 102
I/NaviReceiver(23556): Got BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED
I/NaviReceiver(23556): conn state = 0
```

Comment: this same problem was with my Samsung Galaxy SII....I flashed it for the company boot OS and the problem was changed....but after 1 month,the PCboard was blown out...so kindly take it to the nearer cutomer care centre and do the flash within their service processes.....

Comment: I don't think this it related to what you had, tbh. I had it working before, then not working for a month or so, then working again.

Comment: Also a thought - this might be somehow related to the number of contacts stored on the phone? it seems to fail once reaching 250+ contacts (Refreshed phonebook ME with 255 results) and it is possible that I had less contacts before or my car's phonebook was erased..

Comment: Hey.. any luck with this? I'm facing the same issue.
I dont know if its related, but I see this log whenever this issues is observed:
W/HeadsetBase.cpp( 1631): RFCOMM poll() returned  success (1), but with an unexpected revents bitmask: 0x11
I/HeadsetBase( 1631): headset read error 5